# More efficient rigid 3D transformation in Java

Tags: java, math, optimization, geometry

I want to calculate a rigid 3D transformation between two sets of 3D points. I googled myself, found no suitable implementation and implemented it myself with the help of the Apache Commons Math library, based on this [guide](http://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671). The implementation can be seen below:

```
  public static RigidTransformation3dAnswer computeRigidTransformation3D(RealMatrix src,
      RealMatrix dst) {
    if (src.getRowDimension() == dst.getRowDimension() && src.getColumnDimension() == dst
        .getColumnDimension()) {

      int n = src.getRowDimension();
      RealMatrix centroidSrc = computeCentroid(src);
      RealMatrix centroidDst = computeCentroid(dst);

      RealMatrix aa = src.subtract(tile(centroidSrc, n));
      RealMatrix bb = dst.subtract(tile(centroidDst, n));

      RealMatrix h = aa.transpose().multiply(bb);
      SingularValueDecomposition singularValueDecomposition = new SingularValueDecomposition(h);

      RealMatrix u = singularValueDecomposition.getU();
      RealMatrix vt = singularValueDecomposition.getVT();
      RealMatrix rotationMatrix = vt.transpose().multiply(u.transpose());

      if (new LUDecomposition(rotationMatrix).getDeterminant() < 0) {
        vt.setColumn(2, vt.getColumnVector(2).mapMultiplyToSelf(-1).toArray());
        rotationMatrix = vt.transpose().multiply(u.transpose());
      }

      RealMatrix transpose = (rotationMatrix.scalarMultiply(-1).multiply(centroidSrc.transpose()))
          .add(centroidDst.transpose());

      RigidTransformation3dAnswer answer = new RigidTransformation3dAnswer();
      answer.setRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix);
      answer.setTranslationMatrix(transpose);
      return answer;
    }
    return null;
  }

private static RealMatrix tile(RealMatrix a, int n) {
    RealMatrix realMatrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(n, a.getColumnDimension());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      realMatrix.setEntry(i, 0, a.getEntry(0, 0));
      realMatrix.setEntry(i, 1, a.getEntry(0, 1));
      realMatrix.setEntry(i, 2, a.getEntry(0, 2));
    }
    return realMatrix;
  }

private static RealMatrix computeCentroid(RealMatrix mat) {
    double sumX = 0;
    double sumY = 0;
    double sumZ = 0;
    double[][] returnArray = new double[1][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.getRowDimension(); i++) {
      double a = mat.getEntry(i, 0);
      sumX = sumX + a;
      a = mat.getEntry(i, 1);
      sumY = sumY + a;
      a = mat.getEntry(i, 2);
      sumZ = sumZ + a;
    }
    double centroidX = sumX / (double) mat.getRowDimension();
    double centroidY = sumY / (double) mat.getRowDimension();
    double centroidZ = sumZ / (double) mat.getRowDimension();
    returnArray[0][0] = centroidX;
    returnArray[0][1] = centroidY;
    returnArray[0][2] = centroidZ;
    return new Array2DRowRealMatrix(returnArray);
  }
```

Although this implementation works perfectly, it is not very efficient and takes around 50 ms on desktop, which is not suitable because I want to use it in an Android application.
So here are three question:

a) is there a more efficient library or framework method to use to compute a rigid 3D transformation?

b) If not, is there a heuristic, and therefore more efficient, implementation of such a transformation, if, for example, I exclude the translation and only want rotation around the Z (vertical) axis?

c) If neither of those two points has an answer, is there a way to improve my code efficiency-wise?

Comment: In `src.subtract(tile(centroidSrc, n))` you create a new matrix just for the subtraction and then a new one for the result, even though you don't use `src` later. It would probably be faster to write a method `void subtractFromEachRow(RealMatrix minuend, RealMatrix subtrahendRow)` that does the subtraction without creating any new matrices. Modify `src` using the `addToEntry` method.

Comment: Also `vt.transpose().multiply(u.transpose())` is the same as `u.multiply(vt).transpose()`, but the latter is faster. However, since `vt` and `u` are small, that shouldn't change much.

Comment: How many point pairs do you have?

Comment: Normally around 7, 10 is the maximum

Comment: Ok, then 50ms is very slow, indeed. I think the most important factor is the allocation of new memory as @Socowi pointed out. If that does not help, you need to profile where the time is spent. Minor thing: You can calculate the determinant of a 3x3 matrix directly and do not need to calculate a LU decomposition.